# Data is not showing in blade file when i pass data from controller

Tags: laravel

/// controller

public function productDetails($id){

```
    $product=Product::find($id);
    
    DB::table('product_tracks')->insert(['product_id'=>$id]);
    
    $products=DB::table('products')
                ->join('categories as c','c.id','products.category_id')
                ->join('deliverytimes as dt', 'dt.id', 'products.deliverytimes_id')
                ->where('products.category_id', $product->category_id )
                ->orwhere('products.deliverytimes_id', '=', $product->deliverytimes_id)
                ->select('products.*','c.name as category', 'dt.delivery_time as delivery')
                ->latest()
                ->get()
                ->take(12);
                //dd($products);
    return view('frontend.product_details', compact('product','products'));

}
```

///in blade

Delivery Time  {{ $product->delivery ?$product->delivery->delivery_time :''}}

[image]

Comment: what data returns by `dd($products);` ? can you show

Comment: no after i did it comment out, but now also it's not showing

Comment: Can You Just Remove →orwhere  And Do where() Condition ? @Siddharth

Comment: @vivekvaghela veghela Brother, i did this, But it's still not working.

Comment: $product->delivery->delivery_time ... dd this and see if have any value

Comment: {{ $products->delivery ?$product->delivery->delivery_time :''}} Try This .. You write  Product Insted Of Products .. in controller you have 2 varible .. product and products .. but in your condition .you only do product ..so i think this is the error. @NirjonRoy

Comment: Maybe your $product don't have delivery, can you try `dd($product->delivery)` ? If it says null then you don't have it

Comment: @ChanYungKeat bro yeah it's saying null. then what next.....

Comment: public function delivery(){

        return $this->belongsTo('\App\deliverytime');
    }

Comment: @NirjonRoy yeah, if it says null then it means the product just does not have the delivery, check in your database and your code for the relationship to see if they are related correctly